# Error al leer ficheros estáticos desde el servidor

Tags: javascript, nodejs, gulp

Estoy realizando pruebas con gulp para desplegar mi servidor NodeJS y concatenar e importar todos los estilos y archivos js de una vez.

He conseguido arrancar el servidor, y que todos mis ficheros js y css se unifiquen en uno solo, que es el que llamo desde mi fichero HTML.

Este es el código de mi Servidor.

```
var express = require('express');
var ejs = require ('ejs'); 

var app = express(); 

var render = ejs.renderFile;
app.engine('html', render);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('../js/build/home');

});

app.listen(3000)
```

y este mi fichero gulpfile.js

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require ('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require ('gulp-uglify');
var nodemon = require ('nodemon'); 

gulp.task('building', function(){
    gulp.src('js/source/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('todo.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js/build/'));
}); 

gulp.task('styling', function(){
    gulp.src('js/source/*.css')
    .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js/build'));
})

gulp.task('develop',['building', 'styling'], function () {
  nodemon({ script: 'server.js'
          , ext: 'html js css'
          })
    .on('restart', function () {
      console.log('restarted!')
    })
})
```

Sin embargo, al referenciar desde mi HTML a js/build/todo.js o js/build/styles.css me dice que no puede encontrar el recurso. He probado poniendo unicamente el nombre del fichero y un sinfin de rutas posibles, y siempre da el mismo error. Deduzco que me falta algún tipo de indicación pero no soy capaz de averiguarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas **especificar** qué directorio será utilizado para servir contenido estático. Ésto lo haces mediante un middleware en express. Por ejemplo, suponiendo que guardas tus bundles js y css en el directorio `assets` (en el mismo nivel que tu aplicación), entonces basta con:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets'));
```

Lo que hará express es, que, en cada petición comprueba si se requiere contenido estático por medio de la extensión del archivo. Si es verdad, coge el nombre del recurso solicitado y lo busca dentro del directorio estático. Cuando lo encuentra, lo devuelve con el respectivo content type.

Luego de ésto, necesitas referenciar tus bundles como rutas relativas:

```
<link rel="stylehseet" href="/css/build/styles.css" />
<script src="/js/build/todo.js"></script>
```